# __attribute__((constructor)) && __attribute__((destructor)) in multithreaded app

Tags: c, constructor, thread-safety, destructor

I have an app that I am currently writing in C , where I have several TLS static global variables declared inside a library which is part of the project.

The TLS variables are declared using gcc's __thread directive.

I would like to know if I can use .ctor && .dtor sections to initialise TLS data on a per thread basis inside a shared or static C library, and how thread safe using this method is.

Will the .ctor && .dtor sections be executed per thread or they exist only in the parent process?

On a final note , the library compiles either statically or dynamically to application code , does this mean the .ctor && .dotr sections decalred in the shared/static library will be part of the final executable?

I am really confused about the threading part mostly ... anyone who has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no call back that you could activate on the launching of threads. This would be a performance killer, I think: any naive programmer could add such a callback by accident and all of the sudden *every* thread of the program, even those that don't access that TLS would slow down.

For gcc's `__thread` as well as for the corresponding C11 feature `_Thread_local` only a static initialization is foreseen. That is the same value for every copy which must be determined at compile time is used.

Comment: If there are no callbacks , then how are TLS global static variables initialised in a multi-threaded application? I believe that stating there will be unnecessary overhead is incorrect since the need for TLS variables arise from the fact that you need unique/separate variables every time a thread is in execution .. therefore makes no sense to say that initialising them dynamically and deleting them dynamically introduces unnecessary overhead ... unless I am missing your point.

Comment: I think, the overhead of initializing the copy for a thread is done when the TLS is first accessed by the thread, not when the thread starts up. And then, there is only static data that is copied onto the newly created object, no specific function is called. And internally there might be functions that are called, but there is no callback feature to plug in user specific code at the creation. *There is* a callback mechanism for the deletion of TLS.

Comment: I have just tested with __attribute__((constructor)) and it seems to initialise the TLS variables when the thread is created .. how is this possible and is there a chance that if more threads start up then there will be undefined behaviour?

Comment: I also found this https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mojos/kernel/crt/src/tlsdyn.c

Comment: These are really only questions that you can ask your compiler implementor. You'd have to look into how they implement it. My guess would be that they have one block of memory with the initial values for TLS and on startup of each thread they might just copy that block over to a private block for the thread. Something similar to a copy-on-write for memory mapped files or segments.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's probably a question for your `libc` implementor rather than your compiler implementor. I found in my own tests that ctor functions do run in every thread, so (for those future people viewing this) --- be careful not to do anything that would be unsafe to do repeatedly in your ctor functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and see what happens, but it's best not to rely on behaviour you can't find defined in the manual - it's liable to change without notice.

As far as I know, `__attribute__((constructor))` applies only to global data running at *load time*. Trying to mix that with TLS might be undefined, or might only initialise the data for the master thread.

Comment: Tested it , and seems to work fine so far ,Everytime a thread is created the .ctor & .dtor sections are invoked per thread and TLS variables are created and destroyed as expected.

Comment: Tested it a bit more, and seems to work fine so far , Every time a thread is created the .ctor & .dtor sections seem to be invoked and TLS variables are created and destroyed as expected. I am not quite sure that this behaviour will be the same if many threads are running together ... I am still to test this out .. I wish I could get someone who has already done this type of tests since I am not so good at doing them , I always miss something ..

Answer (score 1):

pthread_key_create creates tls entry with destructor callback;

example usage is here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_create

However you have to set the tls variable in a thread, otherwise the destructor callback is not called.